# Steam running linux and wine at the same time

Tags: steam, linux, wine

Would it be possible to have Steam run linux ready games natively, and non-linux based games through wine without having to run two instances of Steam?

Comment: currently, no :(

Comment: @stasiomod *falls into pieces* that is very sad, they have a linux documentation on how to do this but they didnt write that into the code that is so easy to implement.

Comment: @staiomod one of the reasons this isn't in steam is because they want to get developers to create native Linux games instead of relying on wine

Comment: @Qwertie That's a poor excuse for poor functiionality. Some of the games on Steam were made by companies that don't exist anymore. Is whatever company that bought the company that bought the company that bought the company... that used to be the dev of a 10+ year old game supposed to port it now? For new games it makes sense, but not everything is new.

Answer (score 5):

Now is posible to connect two clients, e.g. Linux-native and Wined-steam, in same machine in same os.

The dual login is now possible because of Steam Home Streaming feature, the restriction login changes and life goes easier for us.

http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/

> START STREAMING TODAY
>   1 Log into Steam on your Windows* PC 
>   2 Log into Steam on another computer on the same network 
>   3 Visit your Steam library to start streaming between them

*NOTE: IDK if Mac users can use this feature, but Linux user can use Home Streaming, i use it daily the webpage is outdated (10/22/2014).

Answer (score 4):

Even if it could be technically possible, you can't be logged on the same Steam account at the same time in two different clients, and I imagine that you wouldn't have two accounts with games split around.

Running games on wine would also be game-dependant more than steam-dependant since each game has it's own requirements and prerequisites, therefore some might work, some might not. A better solution would be running dual boot, or a virtual machine, with both linux and windows, but I wouldn't rely on a virtual machine's performance.

Comment: `you can't be logged on the same Steam account at the same time in two different clients` Actually, you can. Since in-home-streaming is a thing.